# In Unity3D How to Generate custome physics outline border points at runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to Generate custom physics shape outline points at run time in unity, so that I can use those points later on. currently I'm doing it manually through Gizmos points.

example shown in the images below [sprite without border points] is my sprite and expected output will be [sprite with border points] or [custom physics shape] something like this.

is there any solution to do custom physics shape outline point via code ? this will be very helpful for me.

[sprite with border points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGvI6.png)

[sprite without border points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMHwj.png)
[image: custom physics shape]

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the locations of the vertices you want to use, then you can use those vertices to create a [Mesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html). Once you have the mesh you can use it as the sharedMesh for a [MeshCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshCollider.html), which lets you use arbitrary shapes for physics collisions.